# Dropdown-check-list for asp.net gets duplicated in every postback

Tags: asp.net, drop-down-menu

I am using the [dropdown-check-list](http://code.google.com/p/dropdown-check-list/) plug-in to create a dropdownlist that allows multiple selection.

However, it is getting duplicated in every postback after it has been used, which produces something like this:

[image]

Does anyone know why this is happening and how to fix it?

**UPDATE**: About the request to show some code:

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_endRequest(load_lazyload);
    load_lazyload();
    ...
}

function load_lazyload() {
    $("#ContentPlaceHolder1_userControl1_listBoxMultiValueNumbers").dropdownchecklist();
    ...
}
```

C#: this is how the listBox is being populated:

```
listBoxMultiValueNumbers.DataTextField = ds.Tables[0].Columns["number"].Caption;
listBoxMultiValueNumbers.DataValueField = ds.Tables[0].Columns["number"].Caption;
listBoxMultiValueNumbers.DataSource = ds;
listBoxMultiValueNumbers.DataBind();
listBoxMultiValueNumbers.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("Select numbers", "-1"));
UpdatePanelUCCNFT.Update();
```

Comment: do you have **!IsPostBack** checked?? and some code will help

Comment: @huMptyduMpty yes, it is being checked. I have just added some code. I may be wrong, but I think this behaviour is only related to the client side code, since everything in the server side is working as expected

Comment: @huMptyduMpty this may be helpful: if I click on the duplicates of the listBox, it only expands the first one with the possible values. And if I modify one of them, all of them will get the same selected values

Answer (score 1):

i think you have load your dropdown on page load without using postback event..that's why its binding everytime..

```
use page_load()
{
  if(!ispostback)
  {
     //load your dropdown here
  }    
}
```

Comment: I wish you were right. But I am already checking the ispostback and it keeps duplicating the control in the client side

Answer (score 0):

I don't if you still have the problem or not. I just encountered similar problem where I had, dropdownlist gets duplicating after every postback. This solved my problem

```
fillDropDownList()
{
 String selectValue = DropDownList.SelectedValue();
 DropDownList.Items.Clear(); // to clear the duplicates
 DropDownList.SelectedValue = selectValue; // to restore previously selected value
 DropDownList.Items.Insert("0", New ListItem(" Select ", ""));
 DropDownList.DataBind();
}
```

in the page_load

```
if (Page.IsPostBack)
  {
   fillDropDownList();
  }
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: my problem is not related to the dropdownlist but to the dropdown-check-list which is not the same. thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

You're calling the load function twice, thus getting two drop downs. Once registered with `...add_endRequest(load_lazyload)` and again explicitly. I'd guess if you remove the call to `add_endRequest` it would fix it (after all, you already have it wrapped in `$(document).ready()`)